# When I click on an Object with an Audio Source all sounds of the game play at the same time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a sound game for kids where they have to place notes in the proper line that sounds like the note. So  I need the notes and the lines to play a sound when clicked so i made a script that look like this to use in all the game objects that are going to play a sound:

```
public class Playable : MonoBehaviour
{
    private AudioSource audioSource;
    private AudioClip sfx;
    void Start()
    {
        audioSource = gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        sfx = audioSource.clip;
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            audioSource.PlayOneShot(sfx);
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is that when i click on any object all the sounds start playing at the same time and I don't know how to fix it. What can I do?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow ! Since I assume this script is attached to every object in your scene, each one of them will execute it's update function and find your mouse button pressed. You should add a condition to check which object is targeted

Comment: Sounds like each note needs to be a UI Button which when clicked (I think there is an OnClick event) will play it's clip. Should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: Or you need to check which object they are over and only let that be clicked

Answer (score 2):

FIXED: I changed Input.GetMouse.Down to an OnMouseDown method (gameObject needs to have a collider for it to work).